# Group Multilevel JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Not sure if the question title is self descriptive or not but here is the problem statement: **I want to convert a multilevel JSON to a multilevel grouped json**. The idea is to use this JSON data to create accordion. Is there any library which can help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

**JSON I have -**

```
[
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "BOT",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "CPSM",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "DEA",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 8,
        "MeasureText": "DEV",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 16,
          "SubMeasureText": "CICD",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "BOT",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 8,
        "MeasureText": "DEV",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 16,
          "SubMeasureText": "CICD",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "CPSM",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 8,
        "MeasureText": "DEV",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 16,
          "SubMeasureText": "CICD",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "DEA",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**What I want -**

```
[
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": [{
            "Name": "CPSM",
            "Rating": 0
          },{
            "Name": "DEA",
            "Rating": 0
          },{
            "Name": "BOT",
            "Rating": 0
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  },{
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 8,
        "MeasureText": "DEV",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 16,
          "SubMeasureText": "CICD",
          "Apps": [{
            "Name": "BOT",
            "Rating": 0
          },{
            "Name": "CPSM",
            "Rating": 0
          },{
            "Name": "DEA",
            "Rating": 0
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can easily do it manually iterating the JSON, as long as the key ("Apps") on which to group is fixed ....

Comment: should be `Measures` and `SubMeasures` an array?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have 10 apps per measure and I have 3 sets of measures/submeasures but they way it is coming from service is how I shown in sample. I get 30 set of  json objects and I want to group it to 3 objects containing 10 apps each.

Comment: that means yes?

Comment: no, only array in a json object will be apps.

Comment: then i don't understand the question. please add some examples of different measures and submeasure and their result.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I have updated sample. Hope I was able to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table as reference to same `AssessmentId` and `MeasureId`.

If no hash exist, then build a new object with a copy of the actual (no mutation of the original data) and take the `Apps` value into an array. Push the temporary opbejct to the result array and keep the reference to the `Apps` array in the hash table.

If a known hash is found, then just update the array.

```js
var data = [{ Assessment: { AssessmentId: 3, AssessmentText: "CRM", Measures: { MeasureId: 6, MeasureText: "CF", SubMeasures: { SubMeasureId: 12, SubMeasureText: "TNCF", Apps: { Name: "BOT", Rating: 0 } } } } }, { Assessment: { AssessmentId: 3, AssessmentText: "CRM", Measures: { MeasureId: 6, MeasureText: "CF", SubMeasures: { SubMeasureId: 12, SubMeasureText: "TNCF", Apps: { Name: "CPSM", Rating: 0 } } } } }, { Assessment: { AssessmentId: 3, AssessmentText: "CRM", Measures: { MeasureId: 6, MeasureText: "CF", SubMeasures: { SubMeasureId: 12, SubMeasureText: "TNCF", Apps: { Name: "DEA", Rating: 0 } } } } }, { Assessment: { AssessmentId: 3, AssessmentText: "CRM", Measures: { MeasureId: 8, MeasureText: "DEV", SubMeasures: { SubMeasureId: 16, SubMeasureText: "CICD", Apps: { Name: "BOT", Rating: 0 } } } } }, { Assessment: { AssessmentId: 3, AssessmentText: "CRM", Measures: { MeasureId: 8, MeasureText: "DEV", SubMeasures: { SubMeasureId: 16, SubMeasureText: "CICD", Apps: { Name: "CPSM", Rating: 0 } } } } }, { Assessment: { AssessmentId: 3, AssessmentText: "CRM", Measures: { MeasureId: 8, MeasureText: "DEV", SubMeasures: { SubMeasureId: 16, SubMeasureText: "CICD", Apps: { Name: "DEA", Rating: 0 } } } } }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = [o.Assessment.AssessmentId, o.Assessment.Measures.MeasureId].join('|'),
        temp;

    if (hash[key]) {
        hash[key].push(o.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
        return;
    }
    hash[key] = [o.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps];
    temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
    temp.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps = hash[key];
    result.push(temp);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `hash=Object.create(null)` instead of simply `hash={}`?

Comment: @cars10m, if you have a key like `toString`, then it's a prototype of `Object`, but unwanted here.

Answer (score 0):

If all `Assessment` objects have the same `AssessmentId`, you can use **[`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** over the data like this:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(s, d, idx){
    if(idx==0){
      let apps = [];
      apps.push(s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
       s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps = apps;
    }else{
  s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
    }
    return s;
}, data[0]);
```

**Explanation:**

Initialize your `result` object with the first item in your `data` array, using `data[0]`and pass it throught `.reduce()` call, and transform its `Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps` to an `array` then push all the `Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps` on it on each iteration.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "BOT",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "CPSM",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "DEA",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

var result = data.reduce(function(s, d, idx){
    if(idx==0){
      let apps = [];
      apps.push(s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
       s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps = apps;
    }else{
  s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
    }
    return s;
}, data[0]);

console.log(result);
```

## Edit:

Well if you can have multiple `SubMeausrement` objects and you want to group them also in an `array`, then you can try this code:

```
var result = {};

data.forEach(function(d, idx) {
  if (idx == 0) {
    let s = d;
    let subMeasures = [];
    let apps = [];

    apps.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
    s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps = apps;
    subMeasures.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures);
    s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures = subMeasures;
    result = Object.assign({}, s);
  } else {
   let found = elemExists(result.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures, "SubMeasureId", d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.SubMeasureId);
    if (found >= 0) {     result.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures[found].Apps.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
    } else {     result.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures);
    }
  }
});
```

Where `elemExists(array, property, val)` is a util function that checks if an `element` exist in `array`, using a specific `property` to compare iterated `objects` and return the `index` of this `object` in that `array`.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "BOT",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 12,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "CPSM",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Assessment": {
      "AssessmentId": 3,
      "AssessmentText": "CRM",
      "Measures": {
        "MeasureId": 6,
        "MeasureText": "CF",
        "SubMeasures": {
          "SubMeasureId": 16,
          "SubMeasureText": "TNCF",
          "Apps": {
            "Name": "DEA",
            "Rating": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

function elemExists(array, property, val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][property] && array[i][property] === val) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var result = {};

data.forEach(function(d, idx) {
  if (idx == 0) {
    let s = d;
    let subMeasures = [];
    let apps = [];

    apps.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
    s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps = apps;
    subMeasures.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures);
    s.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures = subMeasures;
    result = Object.assign({}, s);

  } else {
   let found = elemExists(result.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures, "SubMeasureId", d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.SubMeasureId);
    if (found >= 0) {
      result.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures[found].Apps.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.Apps);
    } else {
      result.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures.push(d.Assessment.Measures.SubMeasures);
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I updated sample input/output a bit. can you please suggest based on that.